# In Dataweave what is the difference between the selector .. and .*?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I see that the documentation says

```
Multi-value  .*keyName  Array of values of any matching keys
Descendants  ..keyName  Array of values of any matching descendant keys
```

But I still don't understand the distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descendant returns an Array of the first occurrence of the key in each nesting level of an Object.
Multi-value returns an Array of all occurrences of the key in the current nesting level of an Object.

If you have this input:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "id": 11,
    "secondLevel": {
        "id": 2,
        "id": 22,
        "thirdLevel": {
            "id": 3,
            "id": 33
        }
    }
}
```

And this script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    "descendant": payload..id, //first occurrence of "id" in each level
    "multivalue": payload.*id, //all occurrence of "id" in the current level (the first level)
    "multivalueSecondLevel": payload.secondLevel.*id, //all occurrence of "id" in the current level (the second level)
    "allTheIds" : payload..*id //all the ID (descendant with multivalue)
}
```

It's going to generate this output:

```
{
  "descendant": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "multivalue": [
    1,
    11
  ],
  "multivalueSecondLevel": [
    2,
    22
  ],
  "allTheIds": [
    1,
    11,
    2,
    22,
    3,
    33
  ]
}
```

More details in https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-cookbook-extract-data#descendants

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easy to like to explain using examples, so based on [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml) you will get the next results:

```
payload.breakfast_menu.food -> First food element

payload.breakfast_menu.*food -> List of food elements

payload.breakfast_menu.*name -> Nothing

payload.breakfast_menu..name -> List of all product name values
```